# How to access mysql database in Linux from Windows using WampServer?

Tags: dual-boot, server, mysql

I have dual boot Windows and Linux in my computer and I installed both WAMP Server in Windows and LAMP Server in Linux. I am working on a website and I wanted both WAMP and LAMP Servers to use the same mysql database. Now I looked at [Can I share MySql database files with Windows on dual boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27075/can-i-share-mysql-database-files-with-windows-on-dual-boot), but it seemed confusing to follow.

I also have ext2fsd ([How to Geek - 3 ways to access your Linux partitions from Windows](http://www.howtogeek.com/112888/3-ways-to-access-your-linux-partitions-from-windows)) installed in Windows and I wondered whether just editing `my.ini` in Windows' 'datadir' to `(linux partition letter):\var\lib\mysql` can do the same thing. Now I tried this but `localhost/phpmyadmin` shows the database but no tables.

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: At what point of the tutorial do you get stuck? Maybe one could help